# How can I find an element with unconstant id and name?

Tags: selenium

Well, I am new to selenium and trying to automate some form pages. 
I was trying to locate and select the field below I pasted, but name and ID are changing every time the page loads. Is there any way to select that field with selenium?
I am using python btw in case that changes anything.

```
                <dd>
                    <input type="text" class="input" name="0e9c304b1edf4e01c023790b6ee5442ac6663bf6" autocomplete="username" required="required" autofocus="autofocus" maxlength="25" id="_xfUid-4-1583549932">

                </dd>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following xpath:

```
//dd/input[@class='input']
```

if there are other inputs then

```
//dd/input[@class='input'][1]
```

or you can try

```
//dd/input[@autocomplete='username']
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It helped, but not all the way through. So I managed to figure it out that the "input[@autocomplete='username']" works but not in my case. The element that I'm trying to reach is in a form and that form's tabindex is -1. So I tried to reach the same element in an another similar form with an exception of 'tabindex="1"' and I've interacted with the element. So right now the only question is how can I interact with a form's element that it's tabindex -1.